# Does somebody know of a testcase(s) of libRocket

Tags: c++, interface

Today I implemented the interfaces for libRocket in my engine using OpenGL 3.3. I got a standard [RML file](http://librocket.com/wiki/documentation/RML) and some fonts and images which where needed in this RML file. It seems that the page/RML I'm rendering know is the correct one, but I'm not 100% sure. Also because I still don't know a lot of RML and it is a fairly complex one.

So my question: Are there any testcases for example an RML with images and fonts with the result as it should be rendered in a PNG or some other image format? If there aren't would somebody who actually implemented the libRocket interface correctly be so kind and share a result of a rendering in a PNG with the RML to be rendered?

Comment: What is wrong with the samples provided with libRocket itself?  It has several demos which you could easily port to your own engine, which is exactly what we did.  (Not long before deciding that libRocket was a bad choice, btw, at least for a PC game; it just had too many bugs and architectural limitations and it didn't solve any of the actually _hard_ parts of UI development, e.g. animations and transitions and effects, which Chromium Embedded Framework supports natively as it's supports full HTML5+JS.)